# Can a subclass inherit also the constructor of the parent class, or must every class have its own constructor?

Tags: php, oop

Lets say I have an abstract ParentClass and a ChildClass. ChildClass extends ParentClass. Now ParentClass has got this nice constructor:

```
function __construct($tplFile) {
    $this->$tplFile = $tplFile;
}
```

Will ChildClass automatically inherit this one? And if I don't add any constructor to ChildClass, will I be able to say `$foo = new ChildClass("foo.tpl.php");` so that the constructor of ParentClass gets called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ChildClass will automatically inherit the constructor.

Answer (score 19):

From the PHP manual:

> Note:  Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child
>   class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a
>   call to parent::__construct()  within the child constructor is
>   required.

Comment: Note: Calling parent::__construct() does not redirect parameters. Use this:
    if (func_num_args() > 0)
    {
     $constructorArgs = func_get_args();
     call_user_func_array(array($this, 'parent::__construct'), $constructorArgs);
    }
    else
    {
     parent::__construct();
    }

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions is **yes**.